# REST API: create dependent picklist values

Tags: rest-api, picklist, metadata-api, metadata

I am aware that it is possible to create dependent picklist values using the Metadata API but I want to use the REST API.

I know how to create triggers, classes, and pages but I can't wrap my head around picklist values, nevermind their dependency.

Is this possible at all? If so what would the body of the request look like? I am guessing the service URL would be:

```
/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/standardvalueset
```

I have seen a few unresolved older threads on this topic but I am hoping things have changed by now.

Answer (score 1):

The REST API (/services/data/vXX.X/sobjects/) is strictly a user-level API. It does not allow you to modify any metadata components, including fields, objects, layouts, and so on. If you want RESTful access to metadata configuration, use the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/) instead (/services/data/vXX.X/tooling/). The [StandardValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_standardvalueset.htm) is supported.

Comment: Ok. Tooling API works! But I am still having difficulty putting together the request body; How do I link the new value to the picklist field? How do I create the field dependency? It seems EntityParticle is what I should use but it only allows GET requests. By the way do you know if all of this can be done in production orgs?

Comment: To further elaborate, I cannot access PicklistMaster or ValueSet via the REST API (tried Tooling and Metadata API's). I believe this is what I need to create and link it to a StandardValueSet (or CustomField in case of a non-standard picklist). But I don't know how to do it. Of course creating the dependency remains as another problem!